# Enabling/Disabling NSLayoutConstraints in InterfaceBuilder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

`NSLayoutConstraint` (in `iOS 8.0`) has a `BOOL` property called `active` which makes it easy to disable/enable said layout constraint on-the-fly.

To create a second layout set for a view controller which I can then programmatically enable/disable (via an `IBOutletCollection` of `NSLayoutConstraints` for both sets) , I'll need to disable my already defined layout constraints in interface builder.

Let me clear here I do NOT want to delete them, just disable them so that i can design a second set without interface builder complaining all the time about mismatching constraints.
Furthermore switching size classes is not an option, since the layout sets are meant for one and the same size class.

Is there an option to do so?

Thanks in Advance

Malte

Further Information: `SDK Version: 8.1` `Deployment Target 8.0`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Select the constraint you want to disable in storyboard, and <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to show Attributes Inspector, then unselect Installed.

Comment: Wow thanks that worked, i really though unchecking installed would make them inaccessible in this size class! Thanks a lot!

Comment: In Xcode 8 you have to check "Use trait variation" option in order to enable it.

Comment: @AmmarMujeeb Where do you do that?

Comment: And then you can set the `isActive` property in code to re-"install" the constraint?

Comment: This can cause problem when the user put the app in background and comes back to it.

Answer (score 18):

I'd previously used the solution provided by Gabbler successfully, but recently I tried the same thing using Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7 and found that it no longer worked. Constraints that were set as not installed were, as one might expect, not installed at all and had no effect on the layout when switched on or off.

My solution to the problem was to ensure that all constraints were Installed and to add a user-defined runtime attribute with the key 'active', type 'boolean' and value 'false'.

The user-defined runtime attribute panel can be found in the Identity Inspector underneath the Custom Class fields.

Comment: Nice work-around. However, you still get all the Interface Builder warnings and errors linked to conflicting constraints. I wonder why there's no checkbox provided for the active attribute that would solve this sort of thing.

Comment: Yes, it's not especially pleasant, but I don't know a fully IB-compliant fix. Hopefully a future version of Xcode will recognise the need for this setting.

Comment: You could always set the priority of the constraint marked not active to 9999 to silence the warnings.

Comment: Since the release of iOS9, it's generally easier and neater to use UIStackView to handle layouts where elements have to appear and disappear.

Comment: @Ash but not for all situations. For example I have different states to my UI, and for different state I need different constraints to be activated. For example a user profile flying from one side of a screen to another.

Comment: @SimonMoshenko - for an action like that, I'd be more likely to either attach an IBOutlet to one (or more) constraint and edit its settings to produce the effect, or make use of the animatable nature of the `transform` property of `UIView`, though naturally it would depend heavily on the exact requirements. Another (rather fiddly) option might be to have two separate screens and use a custom transition, or use a `UICollectionView` with two different custom layouts to animate the change. So many options these days!

Answer (score 5):

My solution using Xcode 8 and Swift 3 without getting any warnings was unchecked the *Installed* box on Interface builder, Inspector tab:

[image: Installed box on Interface builder]

Then create the IBOutlets and add/remove them programmatically on **viewDidLayoutSubviews()**

```
view.removeConstraints([constraints to remove, ...])
view.addConstraints([constraints to add, ...])
```

Make sure to remove the constraints first, otherwise you will get the message log *Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints...*

Answer (score 3):

For this particular case, I'd declare my constraints in code.

```
// Card View Animatable Constraints
private lazy var cardViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = cardView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500)
private lazy var cardViewEqualHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = cardView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.8)
```

You can then activate or deactivate them whenever you want.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    cardViewHeightConstraint.isActive = true
    cardViewEqualHeightConstraint.isActive = false
}
```

And you still can do most of your layout in interface builder. You can set a constraint that will be removed at runtime so that Interface Builder will still reflect the appearance of your layouts (or at least one of them). Simply create a constraint and check the "Remove at build time" attribute.

[image: In a constraint's size or attribute inspector, check the "Remove at build time" box.]

What this achieves:

- You got to still use Interface Builder for most of your layout
- You won't have any IB warnings
- It works.

The only downside is that interface builder will not be able to fully represent your layout.

Comment: in Xcode 12, this checkbox is not showing. guide please.

Answer (score 0):

### Installed checkbox *DOES NOT WORK*.

As pointed out by @Ash,

The installed checkbox is **not the same** as deactivating/activating a constraint.

Unchecking Installed will (of course!) stop the warning on storyboard.

But the constraints **will not function properly** in code.

Very annoyingly, if you uncheck the Installed checkbox, ***you won't get errors in code or at runtime BUT you WILL get incorrect behavior.***

### Correct solution is very simple:

As pointed out by @bencallis , simply set the priority of one of the two constraints to "999" rather than "1000".  And you're done.

### Don't forget, in the code deactivate first

As user @rgkobashi points out, in your deactivate/activate code pair, must deactivate first.

Here's some full typical example code:

```
// so the logic is that ONE of these TWO constraints will be in use:

@IBOutlet var ratioConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var bottomToScreenBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    layout(forPortraitVLandscape:size.isPortrait)
}

func layout(forPortraitVLandscape: Bool) {
    if (forPortraitVLandscape) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([bottomToScreenBottomConstraint])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([ratioConstraint])
        print("** portrait style")
    }
    else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([ratioConstraint])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([bottomToScreenBottomConstraint])
        print("** landscape style")
    }
}
```