# Toggling a constraint under a certain condition

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

Setup: I have designed an `UIButton` with a bottom `constraint` X, priority 999. In addition to this `constraint` the `UIButton` also has another `constraint` Y, priority 1000 but this one is marked `installed = false`.

Y is being linked to an `@IBOutlet` in my `UIViewController` with a strong reference.

On `viewDidLoad()`: If a given condition happens to be true, I activate `constraint` Y by doing `Y.isActive = true`, and then `view.layoutIfNeeded()`, which eventually calls `updateConstraints()` if needed. If the condition is false, I do nothing.

My expectation: when the condition is true, I expect the view to apply the Y `constraint` to the button and drop X. When the condition is false, I expect the `UIButton` to only have `constraint` X.

The result: It seems like `constraint` Y is not being applied at all, even when the condition is met.

I would appreciate any thoughts on this, this to me seems like something that should work.

Thanks.

P.S. I use swift, but I don't mind if the answer provided is in Obj-C.

Comment: If all that changes between the two constraints is the `constant` then just use a single constraint and change that.

Comment: try to call this inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews will probably work because it will overwrite whatever happens to the constraints and execute at the end, however, this doesn't seem like a solution for why this wouldn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There seems to be a bug when using IB, where setting the property of a constraint as uninstalled will not always work properly as being 'inactive' but rather it will later create problems when activating/deactivating the given constraint.

As a workaround, always mark the constraints as installed, but for those constraints that need to be inactive on load, go to the identity inspector / user defined runtime attributes and add 'active' as a boolean set to false (unchecked)

Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33079428/691868